# How to convert csv to parquet in ADF using copy activity?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

how to convert csv to parquest in adf through copy activity

facing below error
[image]
Column name cannot contain these character:[,;{}()\n\t=],Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,

Comment: It seems you have space in the column name. In ADF, **White space in column name is not supported for Parquet files**. Remove the space and try. Refer [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-parquet#dataset-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Parquet format limitation, not an ADF limitation. If you use a Data Flow activity, instead of a Copy activity, it's much easier. Just add a Derived Column in your data flow with the pattern pictured below to remove all column name spaces. If you are stuck using Copy, you can try [this suggestion here](https://www.techtalkcorner.com/parquet-files-column-names-with-spaces/).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so  much for your answer